# Data from EPSG dataset in proj format

Tags: sql, proj, epsg

In the EPSG dataset obtained from https://epsg.org/home.html where to find the values to fill up the field of +proj =" or +zone= " (to be in proj.4 string)from the database itself? Will the data be taken from a given table or is it taken from somewhere else or is it hardcoded?

Comment: I prefer use the Spatial reference site, replace your EPSG code in this URL : https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/proj4/ (instead of `4326` WGS84 EPSG code).

Comment: My intention is to get the values associated with from the database itself.

Comment: Another useful website for what you are looking for is https://epsg.io/. You may find many different formats of projection files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proj library is implementing the coordinate operations which are defined in the EPSG database. EPSG does not control the downstream project and it does not provide proj strings. The Proj strings are not stored as text in any place of the Proj library either. However, you can query the strings with Proj utility program "projinfo" https://proj.org/apps/projinfo.html.

Usage example:

```
projinfo epsg:3857 -o proj
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
```

The newest Proj versions are using WKT instead of proprietary proj strings and once applications have been upgraded to use current Proj you can use the EPSG site for queries either in WKT or perhaps in GML format.

https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/3857

https://epsg.org/crs/gml/id/3857